# Meaning of "Hitch Back"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading *The Caves of Steel* by Isaac Asimov. In it, there is a quote:

> Baley *hitched his jacket back* [...] so that his blaster butt was
> ready for snatching.

It isn't very clear where the blaster is on Baley's body, so I can think of two possible meanings of *hitching back* here:

1. The blaster is at his waist, meaning he moves the bottom of his jacket back so his hands can reach his waist.

[image]

2. The blaster is near his chest or in his jacket, meaning he opens the top of his jacket a bit so he can readily pull it out (think a secret agent pulling their pistol out of their trenchcoat).

[image]

What does *hitching back* mean in this context?

Comment: Did you consider the first entry in the [dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hitch)? This [copyrighted picture](https://previews.123rf.com/images/scottff72/scottff721711/scottff72171100004/89357116-portrait-of-a-male-cowboy-outlaw-in-a-traditional-western-outfit-prepared-to-draw-his-weapon-3d-rend.jpg) shows what is meant.

Comment: I assume it is in his back pocket, which is why he hitched his jacket *back*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest interpretation of the phrase "hitch back" -

> 1. The blaster is at his waist, meaning he moves the bottom of his jacket
>      back so his hands can reach his waist.

I think it's basically because he is hitching his jacket *back*, meaning, moving *back* his jacket to reach his pocket (of course the jacket would come in the way of the pocket!). If he had to remove it from the front, he could technically just slip his hand right in without the need of hitching *back* (or pull forward in this case) his jacket.